# Positive/negative definiteness of quadratic form on a linear subspace: bordered Hessian criterion

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, reference-request, quadratic-programming

Let $Q$ be a quadratic form on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $G:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ a linear map, and $V=\ker G$. There's a [criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Bordered_Hessian) for the positive/negative definiteness of $Q|_V$ involving minors of the "bordered Hessian" of $Q$, roughly the matrix obtained by "bordering" the matrix of $Q$ by the components of the matrix of $G$.

This criterion is used in calculus, for constrained optimization in the context of Lagrange multipliers.

> How to prove this criterion? (Or where can I find a proof?)

Wikipedia's page on "Hessian matrix", as well as on "Lagrange multipliers" and "Quadratic optimization", and those of the references cited there that I checked, seem to be of no help.